# How to restrict Shipping Method Based on Product in the add-to-cart?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento1.9.2.3, selection

I have couple of shipping methods DHL & FedEx, if selected products exits in cart show only selected shipping method, how to achieve using shopping cart pricing rule  or any other way to do this?

Comment: archive? do you mean achieve?

Comment: @jscar  Yes, pls check with my updated post

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved with a shopping cart rule. I use a commercial extension from webshopapps called Product Matrix. You can assign a shipping group to products and use that to determine which shipping costs and couriers are available.

Comment: In my store i am using webshopapps Matrix Rate as a shipping method, actually it is working good [weight vs destination], Is possible to add more than one condition using by Matrix Rate. @jscar